# C++ Large numbers power of 10

Tags: c++, if-statement

New to C++ programming. Is there a way make the code better so that it does not have repeated code.

```
if (totalDistance < pow(10, 3)) {
    cout << "\nTotal (approx) travel distance = " << totalDistance << " million km\n" << endl;
}
else if (totalDistance < pow(10, 6)) {
    totalDistance = totalDistance / pow(10, 3);
    cout << "\nTotal (approx) travel distance = " << totalDistance << " billion km\n" << endl;
}
else if (totalDistance < pow(10, 9)) {
    totalDistance = totalDistance / pow(10, 6);
    cout << "\nTotal (approx) travel distance = " << totalDistance << " trillion km\n" << endl;
}
```

Comment: To begin with, you could put your `cout` line in a function.

Comment: You should use `double` literals instead of `pow`. Replace `pow(10,3)` with `1e3`

Comment: If everything works, Code Review stack exchange seems like a better fit for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
cout << "\nTotal (approx) travel distance = ";
if (totalDistance < pow(10, 3)) {
    cout << totalDistance << " million km\n";
else if (totalDistance < pow(10, 6)) {
    cout << totalDistance / pow(10, 3) << " billion km\n";
}else if (totalDistance < pow(10, 9)) {
    cout << totalDistance / pwo(10, 6) << " trillion km\n";
}
```

I am supposing you are not using totalDistance anymore, and you don't need an endl if you are already using '\n'.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest improvement:

```
if (totalDistance < pow(10, 3)) {
    outputDistance(totalDistance); 
}
else if (totalDistance < pow(10, 6)) {
    totalDistance = totalDistance / pow(10, 3);
    outputDistance(totalDistance); 
}
else if (totalDistance < pow(10, 9)) {
    totalDistance = totalDistance / pow(10, 6);
    outputDistance(totalDistance); 
}

private void outputDistance(const double totalDistance) {
cout << "\nTotal (approx) travel distance = " << totalDistance << " trillion km\n" << endl;
}
```